# Dual scale plot with ggplot2: Add legend entry for added variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two dataframe of this kind:

```
dput(plot_1)
plot_1<- structure(list(t_exp = c(479.18330748, 550.09264769, 581.27775562, 
                              602.90277249, 729.74280191, 963.299432, 1186.40357135, 1377.06205603, 
                              1604.97385043, 1977.32706598, 1528.89847687, 2017.83048618, 2558.91142867, 
                              2422.08428098, 2418.86951627, 2248.93633177, 1908.92844943, 479.18330748, 
                              550.09264769, 581.27775562, 602.90277249, 729.74280191, 963.299432, 
                              1186.40357135, 1377.06205603, 1604.97385043, 1977.32706598, 1528.89847687, 
                              2017.83048618, 2558.91142867, 2422.08428098, 2418.86951627, 2248.93633177, 
                              1908.92844943, 479.18330748, 550.09264769, 581.27775562, 602.90277249, 
                              729.74280191, 963.299432, 1186.40357135, 1377.06205603, 1604.97385043, 
                              1977.32706598, 1528.89847687, 2017.83048618, 2558.91142867, 2422.08428098, 
                              2418.86951627, 2248.93633177, 1908.92844943, 479.18330748, 550.09264769, 
                              581.27775562, 602.90277249, 729.74280191, 963.299432, 1186.40357135, 
                              1377.06205603, 1604.97385043, 1977.32706598, 1528.89847687, 2017.83048618, 
                              2558.91142867, 2422.08428098, 2418.86951627, 2248.93633177, 1908.92844943, 
                              479.18330748, 550.09264769, 581.27775562, 602.90277249, 729.74280191, 
                              963.299432, 1186.40357135, 1377.06205603, 1604.97385043, 1977.32706598, 
                              1528.89847687, 2017.83048618, 2558.91142867, 2422.08428098, 2418.86951627, 
                              2248.93633177, 1908.92844943), t_exp_reg = c(26.16551766, 32.54411008, 
                                                                           31.89983946, 33.57790402, 40.57386933, 51.27728681, 72.02726694, 
                                                                           85.89296127, 96.54878305, 125.99423998, 100.51912523, 158.86908483, 
                                                                           208.20248928, 176.42267237, 190.65640004, 176.10542289, 130.7703496, 
                                                                           32.71137458, 39.35283051, 40.59087882, 45.3692821, 60.72202556, 
                                                                           80.76792966, 105.34277987, 116.81838439, 132.64802812, 168.07775832, 
                                                                           112.32696236, 144.44785762, 184.26048785, 181.47032946, 169.40245823, 
                                                                           153.22527354, 144.68736618, 7.74947477, 11.5467708, 15.111152, 
                                                                           16.76515862, 20.21513219, 32.21155115, 49.08098119, 49.34752514, 
                                                                           65.23062284, 90.83448565, 98.68533335, 110.35181638, 155.20134044, 
                                                                           184.11839864, 202.12998344, 202.38291918, 186.14894147, 300.17015871, 
                                                                           338.94189249, 347.69477529, 355.54335399, 419.69931314, 554.38578988, 
                                                                           691.16322191, 839.23036408, 957.08705321, 1162.56265848, 872.12931417, 
                                                                           1206.33027022, 1521.9238857, 1400.98004137, 1300.24106912, 1249.64540352, 
                                                                           1029.14047836, 112.38678176, 127.70704381, 145.98111005, 151.64707376, 
                                                                           188.53246169, 244.6568745, 268.78932144, 285.77282115, 353.45936321, 
                                                                           429.85792355, 345.23774176, 397.83145713, 489.3232254, 479.09283914, 
                                                                           556.43960544, 467.57731264, 418.18131382), year = c(1999L, 2000L, 
                                                                                                                               2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
                                                                                                                               2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 
                                                                                                                               2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
                                                                                                                               2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
                                                                                                                               2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
                                                                                                                               2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
                                                                                                                               2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 
                                                                                                                               2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
                                                                                                                               2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 
                                                                                                                               2014L, 2015L), NO_REGIAO_UF = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                         4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                                                                                                                                         5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                                         3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
                                                                                                                               ), .Label = c("REGIAO SUDESTE", "REGIAO SUL", "REGIAO CENTRO OESTE", 
                                                                                                                                             "REGIAO NORTE", "REGIAO NORDESTE", "REGIAO NAO DECLARADA"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           -85L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

plot_tot<-structure(list(t_exp = c(479.18330748, 550.09264769, 581.27775562, 
                                    602.90277249, 729.74280191, 963.299432, 1186.40357135, 1377.06205603, 
                                    1604.97385043, 1977.32706598, 1528.89847687, 2017.83048618, 2558.91142867, 
                                    2422.08428098, 2418.86951627, 2248.93633177, 1908.92844943), 
                          year = 1999:2015, scaled = c(284.99639069633, 327.170034291692, 
                                                       345.717515109138, 358.579089501427, 434.017757786058, 572.926596136247, 
                                                       705.618769406107, 819.013746111758, 954.565293478285, 1176.0240146804, 
                                                       909.319128707865, 1200.1136029187, 1521.9238857, 1440.54533466909, 
                                                       1438.63333914465, 1337.56482635206, 1135.34363508228)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                             -17L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

`Plot_tot` has data on total exports of Brazil, while  `Plot_1` breaks down this data at the regional level.
My aim is to plot these two measures into a single graph, given that they are in different scales, I use the following command:

```
scl <- max(plot_tot$t_exp)/max(plot_1$t_exp_reg)
ggplot(plot_1, aes(x = year, y = t_exp_reg, color = NO_REGIAO_UF)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Export by Region", x = "Year", y = "Total Export by region (100M US$)", fill = "Region") +
  geom_line(data =plot_tot,aes(y = scaled, x = year),inherit.aes = FALSE, color="#362828",size = 0.8,linetype=2)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 2600, 400), sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*scl, name = "Brazil total exports (100M US$)")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1990,2015,3)) +   
  labs(color = "Legend")
```

The issue with this graph is in the legend. While this solution produces a legend for every region I do not have in the legend the line for the total exports taken from `plot_tot`.
Does anyone know how I can adjust the legend and produce an additional entry explaining that the dashed line indicates total exports?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a separate key for `linetype`:

```r
ggplot(plot_1, aes(x = year, y = t_exp_reg, color = NO_REGIAO_UF)) +
  geom_line()+
  labs(title = "Export by Region", x = "Year", 
       y = "Total Export by region (100M US$)", fill = "Region") +
  geom_line(data = plot_tot,
            aes(y = scaled, 
                x = year, 
                linetype = factor("Total")), 
            inherit.aes = FALSE, size = 0.8)+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(2), breaks = "Total") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 2600, 400), 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*scl, 
                     name = "Brazil total exports (100M US$)")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1990, 2015, 3)) +   
  labs(color = "Regions", linetype = "") +
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(30, "points"))
```

[image]

Comment: Great, this is super useful! Is there any chance you also know how I can make the label on the second y-axis to be readable in the same direction of the label on the main y-axis?    the issue is that one is top-down the other one is bottom-up